# A good way to install python packages not recognized by Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to follow [this BERT tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/classify_text_with_bert?hl=en).
One of the packages is tensorflow-text.

When downloading packages, I usually use the Anaconda Navigator(ver 2.0.4), which I think may prevent conflicts (I'm an amateur, so the prob of being wrong is high).
However, even after updating the index of available python packages,Anaconda does not list the tensorflow-text package as available for download.

Given this situation, how should I proceed? What's a good way to install that package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use pip in the console of the chosen environment.